# Bootstrap 5 Modals and other stuff I define through PHP not working

Tags: php, html, bootstrap5-modal

For the life of me, I can't understand why I am having trouble calling the modal in the following example:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT
            master_traits_index,
            trait_name AS name
        FROM
            `cp_2020_master_traits`
        WHERE
            trait_type = 1;";
$query_result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$attributes = [];

while($gotinfo2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)){
    $attributes[] = $gotinfo2; //assign whole values to array
}

// Attribute Modals 

foreach ($attributes as $row2){
    echo('<div class="modal fade" id="'.$row2['master_traits_index'].'_staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="'.$row2['master_traits_index'].'Label" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="'.$row2['master_traits_index'].'Label">'.$row2['name'].'</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>');
}

foreach ($attributes as $row1) {
    echo('<div class="col">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark position-relative" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#'.$row1['master_traits_index'].'_staticBackdrop">
            <h4>'.$row1['name'].'</h4>
            <p>[ <em id="'.$row1['master_traits_index'].'_final">1</em> ]</p>
            <span class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-dark" id="'.$row1['master_traits_index'].'_cps_spent">0.5 cp</span>
            </button>
        </div>');
}
?>
```

When I inspect the page output, all the ids match in accordance with the buttons, so it should call the modals, but it doesn't. You should be able to use PHP to build this kind of thing when you have large amounts of similar data to manipulate right?

The bottom line is that when I click the button corresponding to the modal created using the variable in the php loops, nothing happens. When I inspect it in my browser. I can't figure out why it's not responding.

Comment: Do you have errors either on server-side or client-side? How is this not working? Do you have ways that you can share so we can easily reproduce the problem?

Comment: Okay, apparently I am woefully ignorant. I'm getting the following errors in the browser:  1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Numeric separators are not allowed at the end of numeric literals, and 2. Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#2_staticBackdrop' is not a valid selector, etc. This is probably why this isn't working.

Comment: I do have errors client-side. They look like they come from defining the div IDs with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is caused by the fact that HTML `id` values cannot start with a number:

[image]

Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

Solution: refactor your HTML and put some prefix before the numeric values. That will fix your HTML `id` attributes. From that point onwards if you have some code that assumed the values of those HTML `id`s, then you will need to refactor that as well.